# Is there a way to create a deferred object wrapper in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wrapper, jquery-deferred

I've been reading a lot about the new jQuery.Deferred object. One thing that'd be really useful would be to be able to convert an existing object into a deferred one, then you'd get 100% flexibility about where you get your data from.

I'm thinking something along the lines of

```
$.makeDeferred({property: "data"}) // returns an object with .promise() method, in resolved state, and that passes the original object as data/context to any callback function
```

Does anyone know if this method already exists, or how to go about creating one?

Comment: see my answer - `$.when` will do this by itself because it checks whether each argument is a promise or not, but you can't call `foo.done()` unless `foo` is a promise.

Comment: ah, yes, I see what you mean now.  Yes, calling `$.when(foo)` does return an already resolved promise when `foo` is a plain object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to wrap your object to get this effect, since most methods that are passed  promises as parameters will treat a plain object as an already-resolved promise.

That said, if you really want this, try this:

```
(function($) {
    $.makeDeferred = function() {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        d.resolve(arguments);
        return d.promise();
    };
))(jQuery);
```

This would at least allow you to also handle the case where you want to call a method *of* the promise, e.g. `my_promise.done()`, as opposed to *passing* the promise, i.e. `$.when(my_promise)`.

[untested, may not work, E&OE, etc.]

**EDIT**

Actually, I thnk all you have to do is wrap your plain-old-data in `$.when`:

```
$.when({property: "data"})
```

Comment: Cheers - feel a bit embarrassed now for missing that in the documentation. Although I do now feel like trying to break it by using when() on an object such as {promise: "only joking"}

Comment: yes, the way of checking whether an object is a promise or not does seem a little brittle...